# Are gcc's STL empty methods threadsafe?

Tags: gcc, stl, thread-safety

If I have a deque or list that's being manipulated on different threads, can I call empty without a lock?  The standard doesn't say anything about threads, so I know this won't be portable, but I'm using gcc 4.4.  I'm also curious to know if this is safe on other implementations in case I ever decide to, say, switch to the intel compiler.  But mostly, I care about gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to provide the thread safety.